# Entity Framework 6 Table Per Hierarchy specific includes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, table-per-hierarchy, tph

I have a problem with EF6 when I do a Table per Hierarchy mapping. I have an `Person` class that has `Employee` and `Manager` children. The two classes are nearly the same, except for one field: DepartmentId (and the subsequent linked component Department).

```
class Person {
  public string Name {get; set;}
}
class Employee : Person {}
class Manager : Person {
  public int DepartmentId {get; set;}
  public Department Department {get; set;}
}
```

I have set up EF with the necessary setup for this kind of thing:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
  modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
     .Map<Employee>(x => x.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("emp"))
     .Map<Manager>(x => x.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("man"));
```

Now my problem is that when I want to include the Department, I can't figure out how to do it. Can anybody help me? Or point me in the right direction with an article or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your dbContext only exposes the `Person` DbSet. Also, you don't indicate if you're trying to get all Person objects or just the Managers. If it's the latter you can use the `OfType<T>` method to cast to the correct type.

```
dbContext.Person
    .OfType<Manager>()
    .Include(m => m.Department)
```